# DB query from PHP gives no result but same query on phpMyAdmin works?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

So I have a simple query that checks a mySQL database for articles and echos the HTML code to generate my blog dynamically. The query works when I run it directly with phpMyAdmin, but when it's called from the .php file, it show "No Results". Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY article_timestamp DESC LIMIT 4;
```

Runs fine when tested on phpMyAdmin. But when it's in my php code it doesn't. PHP code below:

```
<?php

// establish connection
function connect() {
    $connection = mysql_connect ("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname") or die(mysql_error);

    return $connection;
}

$connection = connect();


// define article variables

$article_id;
$article_title;
$article_headline;
$article_image_path;
$article_body;
$article_author;
$article_tags;
$article_timestamp;

$myquery = "SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY article_timestamp DESC LIMIT 4";

$result = mysql_query($connection, $myquery);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $article_id = $row['article_id'];

        $article_title = $row['article_title'];

        $article_headline = $row['article_headline'];

        $article_image_path = $row['article_image_path'];

        $article_body = $row['article_body'];

        $article_author = $row['article_author'];

        $article_tags = $row['article_tags'];


        $article_timestamp = $row['article_timestamp'];

        echo "<!-- Blog Post -->
                <h2>
                    <a href=\"post.php?id=$article_id\">$article_title</a>
                </h2>
                <p class=\"lead\">
                    by $article_author
                </p>
                <p>Posted on $article_timestamp</p>
                <hr>
                <img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"$article_image_path\" alt=\"\">
                <hr>
                <p class=\"lead\">$article_headline</p>
                <a class=\"btn\" style=\"border-color: #4c044d;\" href=\"post.php?id=$article_id\">Read More</a>

                <hr>";
    }
}

else {
    echo 'No Results found';
}

mysql_close ($connection);
?>
```

DB connection should be working fine. I added this code:

```
if ($connection == false) {
   echo 'whoops';
}
```

And the condition is never met when it's placed at various checkpoints. Can someone give me a hand? Spent hours on this and no dice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why declare all the variables twice?

Comment: Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. They are also insecure. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? Checked your error logs?

Comment: You should read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php. It should be `mysql_query($query, $conn)` but you have `mysql_query($conn, $query)` (wrong order). _**This is why you always should check your error log as first course of action.**_

Comment: you are using `mysql_connect()` as `mysqli_connect()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php although it is deprecated api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your connect function like below

```
$connection = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "redhat") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('test');
```

Also please use mysqli  as mysql is deprecated in new versions of php

Comment: After way too much trial and error, I realized that the issue was with my credentials. Cpanel was refusing the user I created to access the DB and so using my original Cpanel credentials did the trick. Thanks for the help. Also, I changed all my DB calls to use mysqli as suggested.

Comment: Welcome ,These comments make me help for many queries asked in stackoverflow .

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL_* is deprecated try to use mysqli_* or PDO

> Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

```
        <?php

    // establish connection
    function connect() {

        $servername = "localhost";  //host name

        $username = "username"; //username

        $password = "password"; //password

        $mysql_database = "dbname"; //database name

        $connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$mysql_database) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

        return $connection;
    }

    $connection = connect();

    $myquery = "SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY article_timestamp DESC LIMIT 4";


     $stmt = $connection->prepare($myquery );

                    //The argument may be one of four types:

                    //i - integer
                    //d - double
                    //s - string
                    //b - BLOB
                    //change it by respectively 

                    $stmt->execute();

                    $get_result =$stmt->get_result();

                    $row_count= $get_result->num_rows;


    if ($row_count > 0) {

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_result)) {
            $article_id = $row['article_id'];

            $article_title = $row['article_title'];

            $article_headline = $row['article_headline'];

            $article_image_path = $row['article_image_path'];

            $article_body = $row['article_body'];

            $article_author = $row['article_author'];

            $article_tags = $row['article_tags'];


            $article_timestamp = $row['article_timestamp'];

            echo "<!-- Blog Post -->
                    <h2>
                        <a href=\"post.php?id=$article_id\">$article_title</a>
                    </h2>
                    <p class=\"lead\">
                        by $article_author
                    </p>
                    <p>Posted on $article_timestamp</p>
                    <hr>
                    <img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"$article_image_path\" alt=\"\">
                    <hr>
                    <p class=\"lead\">$article_headline</p>
                    <a class=\"btn\" style=\"border-color: #4c044d;\" href=\"post.php?id=$article_id\">Read More</a>

                    <hr>";
        }
    }

    else {
        echo 'No Results found';
    }


                    $stmt->close();
                    $connection->close();


    ?>
```